# The moderator option "contact community team" gives a page missing error

Tags: bug, status-completed, moderator-tools

As a Stack Overflow moderator, I just tried to contact the community team via the "contact community team" option on a user's profile. Instead of bringing up the proper form, I'm getting a Page Not Found error.

This appears to be broken for all users, and another moderator confirmed that it's not working on another site.

This was working yesterday, if I remember correctly, so it appears to be a recent regression.

Comment: I can confirm that it's not working on at least four sites.

Comment: I sent one from AU 6 hours ago. Tried again just now and got "Page not found" error. Same on U&L.

Comment: I think that was fixed since - can you check again?

Comment: @Oded - Seems to be fixed, at least for a couple of users I tested on. Can't speak for other sites, but Stack Overflow seems functional again.